# AZCopy not working on macOS: failed to use brand new login token

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azcopy

I have run `az login` to refresh the login token [twice for good measure]. It was successful.   But `az copy` is not working: it is still complaining about a stale token. Why? What is the fix?

```
azcopy copy  --from-to BlobLocal abfss://feed-pipeline-workspace@our-s torage-account.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/nonstream/domain/form/form/snapshot-data.parquet .
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.20.0 is available to download
```

After many minutes ...

```
failed to perform copy command due to error: get cached token failed to ensure token fresh, please log in with azcopy's login command again, adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'.
```

I am on latest `macOS 13.5`

**Update** Apparently there is a different login for `azcopy`: it is

`azcopy login`

I did that and see this

[image]

However `azcopy` still hangs

The log in `~/.azcopy` has this:

```
2023/08/11 20:56:40 AzcopyVersion  10.13.0
2023/08/11 20:56:40 OS-Environment  darwin
2023/08/11 20:56:40 OS-Architecture  amd64
2023/08/11 20:56:40 Log times are in UTC. Local time is 11 Aug 2023 13:56:40
```